# The time functions time.getmtime and time.getctime gives the same result

Tags: python

Below is a program I wrote to determine the folder creation and last modified time of the folder. But both gives the same result. Can you please suggest what change is required to get the required result?

```
import os
import time

t1 = os.path.getmtime('folder path')
t2 = os.path.getctime('folder path')
print time.ctime(t1)
print time.ctime(t2)
```

Comment: and in os this result are not the same?

Comment: my understanding is getmtime will give  last modified time and getctime will give folder creation time? correct me if i am wrong anywhere...

Comment: and if folder just created this values can be the same

Comment: no.folder was created long back and changes was done in the folder recently....

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MorganThrapp ,its MacOS.

Comment: os.path.getctime(path)
Return the system’s ctime which, on some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time for path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Posix system, modification time is the time where the *data* was last modified, creation time is the time where the *file status* was last modified.

For example, if you change access rights or rename the file, its creation time will change but not its modification time. So as the opposite of the `c` would suggest, ctime is generally more recent than mtime.

Here is what man page from `stat` says:

```
 st_atim      Time when file data last accessed.  Changed by the mknod(2),
              utimes(2), read(2) and readv(2) system calls.

 st_mtim      Time when file data last modified.  Changed by the mkdir(2),
              mkfifo(2), mknod(2), utimes(2), write(2) and writev(2) sys-
              tem calls.

 st_ctim      Time when file status was last changed (inode data modifica-
              tion).  Changed by the chflags(2), chmod(2), chown(2),
              creat(2), link(2), mkdir(2), mkfifo(2), mknod(2), rename(2),
              rmdir(2), symlink(2), truncate(2), unlink(2), utimes(2),
              write(2) and writev(2) system calls.
```

Comment: how i can modify above given program using the status function?

Comment: @Maverick: Here `stat` is the underlying low level function called by Python. I just explain why `getctime` is same or younger than `getmtime`, but on a Posix system I cannot imagine how to get a creation time as is it not saved anywhere by the system.